# Capture still images from photo stream using capture engine manager in media foundation

Tags: visual-c++, ms-media-foundation

Thank you very much for your prompt reply. I have posted the sample code which i use to capture image using TakePhoto() method.This method is returning success.
OnCaptureEvent() is used to handle an event from the capture engine and its returning MF_CAPTURE_ENGINE_ERROR error.

```
HRESULT TakePhoto()
{    
    HRESULT hr = m_pEngine->GetSink(MF_CAPTURE_ENGINE_SINK_TYPE_PHOTO, &pSink);
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        goto done;
    }

    hr = pSink->QueryInterface(IID_PPV_ARGS(&pPhoto));
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        goto done;
    }

    hr = m_pEngine->GetSource(&pSource);
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        goto done;
    }

    hr = pSource->GetCurrentDeviceMediaType(1, &pMediaType);        // 1 is Image stream index.I will get current image stream media type here.
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        goto done;
    }

    //Configure the photo format
    hr = CreatePhotoMediaType(pMediaType, &pMediaType2,GUID_ContainerFormatBmp);
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        goto done;
    }  

    hr = pPhoto->RemoveAllStreams();
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        goto done;
    }

    DWORD dwSinkStreamIndex;
    // Try to connect the first still image stream to the photo sink
    if(bHasPhotoStream)
    {
        hr = pPhoto->AddStream((DWORD)MF_CAPTURE_ENGINE_PREFERRED_SOURCE_STREAM_FOR_PHOTO,  pMediaType2, NULL, &dwSinkStreamIndex);         //Instead of MF_CAPTURE_ENGINE_PREFERRED_SOURCE_STREAM_FOR_PHOTO,i gave index as 1.i am getting error
        if(FAILED(hr))
        {           
            goto done;
        }       
    }       

    hr = pPhoto->SetOutputFileName(pszFileName);
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        goto done;
    }

    hr = m_pEngine->TakePhoto();
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        goto done;
    }
    return hr;
}

HRESULT OnCaptureEvent(WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    GUID guidType;
    HRESULT hrStatus;

    IMFMediaEvent *pEvent = reinterpret_cast<IMFMediaEvent*>(wParam);

    hr = pEvent->GetExtendedType(&guidType);
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        if (guidType == MF_CAPTURE_ENGINE_ERROR)            //i got this error if i give dwSourceStreamIndex as '1' in Addstream api
        {
            DestroyCaptureEngine();
        }        
    }

    pEvent->Release();
    return hrStatus;
}
```

Comment: Please [post a small example of your code](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) here.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  What is the error?  I assume this occurs on the line where you call GetExtendedType, correct?  Is pEvent in a good state?

Comment: Error occur in that line only and pEvent is in a good state before Takephoto() method call.Actually i wanna capture image from a image strea.Can you please tell me how can i configure image stream while video streaming and capture image?